# Using an iterating variable in a sed double quote

Tags: bash, sed

The task I am trying to complete is to add a certain number of zeros to a column of 2 digit numbers from a text file beginning in a comma eg; ",24".

Using sed I want to do this only on certain lines determined by a counter from a while loop. What I mean is when the counter reaches j=2, it will then use this variable as part of sed to rewrite ",24" as ",00024"on line 2.

So far:

```
count=j

cat A.txt | while read line

do
    j=$((j+1))

echo "$j"

 sed -i "$js/,/,000/" A.txt

done
```

My problem is that sed won't recognise the replacing statement producing this error;

> sed: -e expression #1, char 9: unknown command: `/'

I understand that what I've shown here, sed can do without the iteration, but the iterator is required for a further part of the project.

I feel like the error may lie in the using the \ escape, but nothing I've done has worked so far.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you want to combine sed with a shell loop, rather than just using an address range in sed directly?

Comment: `sed -i "${j}s/,/,000/" A.txt` - bash is looking for a variable called `js`.  The braces tell it that the name of the variable is just `j`.

Comment: The shell looks for a variable named `$js`. You have to use `sed -i "${j}s/...`

Comment: Perfect yeah, that was all I was looking for!

Comment: you know this is highly inefficient.  It's scanning the file for each row.  The time it takes is quadratic to the number of lines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

The final script is:

```
count=j
cat A.txt | while read line
do
    j=$((j+1))
    echo "$j"
    sed -i "${j}s/,/,000/" A.txt
done
```

as [Benjamin W.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w)  told you, the variable **j** needs to be specificied using the expansion bracket **${j}** this avoid to confuse with the inexistent **$js** variable.